# How to manage namesakes in an SQL database?

Tags: sql, mariadb, alias

I will connect my database to some data providers and I need to normalize them in my database.

Explaination:

```
Provider 1 gives me :test
Provider 2 gives me TesT
```

What I need is:

```
test= Test = what i want
```

How to manage this in mariaDB?

Comment: Your question isn't too clear. If you want the data to be the same (in terms of capitalisation), you can run the data through lower().

Comment: You can convert them all to upper case and store them, assuming your database is case sensitive. If your database is storing information without case sensitivity, don't bother changing the case until you do a select.

Comment: That's only the tip of the iceberg!  Plan on writing separate code for each provider.  Don't even think about some trivial mapping like that, at least until after you have written separate code and discover that the code is 'similar'.  (I doubt if you will find such a situation.)  [I speak from experience.]